# Angular loading symbol using ng-show is not working in child pages

Tags: angularjs

I have a single page application there i have added a loader symbol in the master page.

### index.html

```
     <html lang="en" ng-app="SwipeIndex">
        <body>
            <div data-ng-controller="indexController">  
              <p class="text-center" id="loader" ng-show="dataload" ng-init="dataload=false"></p>
            </div>
            <div data-ng-view="">
        </div>
        </body></html>
```

my indexcontroller is as follows

```
var ss= angular.module("SwipeIndex", ['ngRoute', 'LocalStorageModule']);

ss.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/login", {
        controller: "loginController",
        templateUrl: "login.html"
    });
});
ss.controller('indexController', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    $location.path('/login');
}]);
```

i am using angular routing to go to logincontroller and my logincontroller is as follows

```
ss.controller('loginController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {    
  //Setting my loading ng-show value to true, to show loading symbol but it has no effect
  $scope.dataload = true;
}]);
```

but after setting `$scope.dataload=true` also my loader symbol is not getting displayed.

To check whether the loader is working or not i have place true in `ng-show='true'` then it is working fine.

Comment: Where is your ngView directive?

Comment: @dfsq in my index.html file..to reduce the amount of code here..i removed..i have edited the question now

Comment: It doesn't work because your `indexController` and `loginController` are using different scopes so they are using different `dataload` values

Comment: @user2341963 then can you suggest me the best way to achieve this by placing the loader only in the master page.

Comment: See answer from dfsq or you can use events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ngView directive creates new scope for its content. So for this reason setting `dataload` in `loginController` does not affect master page one. The simplest fix in this case is to use `$rootScope` for this.

In `indexController` (you don't need ngInit anymore):

```
$rootScope.dataload = false;
```

and then in `loginController`:

```
$rootScope.dataload = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case dataload is a property of indexController's scope. So its accessible in the same scope.

Solution to your Questions is : 
You should use $rootScope.dataload instead $scope. In this case dataload property will be available in app scope which is accessible anywhere.

you should initialize the dataload property as below

```
SwipeSumo.run(['$rootScope',function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.dataload = false;
  }])
```

Now you can hide/show loader by doing

```
$rootScope.dataload = true; //show loading
$rootScope.dataload = false; //hide loading
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

disagree with the use of $rootScope. Using it for this kind of stuff sure works, but I'm not sure that's what it's supposed to be used for.

Isn't a service more relevant to share behaviors between controllers?

Your controller would just jave to reference an 'isLoading' member exposed by the service, and that member would be manipulated through some methods in it, like setLoading(bool), accessible from the whole app, just not in a scope.

EDIT: Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/1rfvnyrn/). The runBlock just updates the status in the service once every second, and since your controller's scope uses a reference to an object, the binding still works. Of course it's be better to manipulate the status object in an exposed Api, but I tried to keep it simple.

Javascript:

```
angular.module("exampleApp", [])
.service("loaderService", loaderService)
.controller("LoaderCtrl", Loader)
.run(runBlock);

function loaderService() {
    var status = {};
    status.isLoading = false;
    this.status = status;
}

Loader.$inject = ["$scope","loaderService"];
function Loader($scope, loaderService) {
    $scope.loaderStatus = loaderService.status;   
}

runBlock.$inject = ["loaderService", "$interval"];
function runBlock(loaderService, $interval) {
    $interval(function () {
        loaderService.status.isLoading = 
            !loaderService.status.isLoading; 
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. you mean to say, $rootScope is not meant for these type of things. if yes where should i use this.

Comment: putting something in $rootScope is roughly equivalent to declaring a global variable : You can access it in any inheriting scope, with the added risk of conflicting members, bad code readability and such. It is sometimes good to use them, but IMHO you should only do so when no other viable alternative is available.